# React Native 0.61.5 app keeps stopping after upgrade from 0.61.4

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I just rebuilt a react native 0.61.5 app with nodejs 12.16.0 on Win10 platform with Android emulator. My previous version was RN 0.61.4 and was working fine. What I did for upgrade was to init a React Native project and add the modules one by one to the new project. The problem is that my new app keeps stopping after launching with `react-native run-android` successfully. Here is the message on the emulator:

[image]

Here is the log output. The view was detached at the end somehow:

```
PS C:\d\code\js\emps_fe6> npx react-native log-android
info Starting logkitty
[19:59:13] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.ctor()

[19:59:13] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()

[19:59:13] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()

[19:59:15] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
                           │ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
                           └ ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()

[19:59:15] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()

[19:59:15] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge.

[19:59:15] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge

[19:59:15] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge

[19:59:15] D | ReactNative ▶︎ CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()

[19:59:15] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()

[19:59:16] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()

[20:00:11] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.ctor()

[20:00:11] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()

[20:00:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()

[20:00:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
                           │ ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
                           └ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()

[20:00:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge.

[20:00:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge

[20:00:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge

[20:00:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
                           │ ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
                           └ CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()

[20:00:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()

[20:00:13] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()
```

Here is the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "emps_fe615",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^4.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.4",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.1",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
    "socket.io-client": "2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I suspect it is the dependency module(s) upgraded causing the crash but I haven't found one yet. The launch build was successful and bundler is at 100%. The android studio and emulator were restarted and the problem is the same. What could be the issues here causing the app stopping?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? After adding react-native-camera to my app, the same thing happens for me. I'm wondering if there might be a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I notice is that there are a few additional module installation required in rebuild. One of them is module `react-native-screens` which requires additional [setup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screens) before use. After the further setup for `react-native-screens`, the app starts to work fine.